# ag-grid | Get only exactly changed cell data

Tags: javascript, php, ag-grid

Im currently working on cell editing and save data using Ag-grid js library. i figure out showing data. and get data on edit. I have custom cell id, that is include db table column and row ids. im planning to send it to server with value after finish edit. I Used MySQL database to store data.
the custom cell id look like this `"1,4,1,12,47"`.
the data is return whole row data set after finish edit. I just need only changed cell data object.

example pen: https://codepen.io/vidux/pen/vYgKXvp

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if there are any other way to do this but , here  is alternate solution you can use column name because the column name matches with *event.data* so using that column name get required data like this `event.data[cols]` where cols is `event.column.colDef.headerName`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
// specify the columns
const columnDefs = [

  {
    field: "model.value",
    headerName: "Model"
  },
  {
    field: "make.value",
    headerName: "Make"
  },
  {
    field: "price.value",
    headerName: "Price"
  },
];

const autoGroupColumnDef = {

}

// let the grid know which columns and what data to use
const gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: columnDefs,

  defaultColDef: {
    flex: 1,
    minWidth: 110,
    editable: true,
    resizable: true,
  },
  onCellValueChanged: onCellValueChanged,
};



function onCellValueChanged(event) {
  console.clear()
  console.log('data after changes is: ', event.data);
  var cols = event.column.colDef.headerName.toLowerCase()
  console.log('data column name--', event.column.colDef.headerName.toLowerCase());
  console.log('data after changes is: ', event.data[cols]);
}





// setup the grid after the page has finished loading
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // lookup the container we want the Grid to use
  const eGridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');

  // create the grid passing in the div to use together with the columns & data we want to use
  new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions);

  let jsonObj = `[
  { "make":{"value": "Toyota", "cell_id":"22,331,1"}, "model": {"value": "Hilux", "cell_id":"22,331,2"}, "price": {"value": 80899, "cell_id":"22,331,3"} },
   { "make":{"value": "MBW", "cell_id":"22,332,1"}, "model": {"value": "I8", "cell_id":"22,332,2"}, "price": {"value": 300899, "cell_id":"22,332,3"} }
]`;


  gridOptions.api.setRowData(JSON.parse(jsonObj));




  gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.min.noStyle.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myGrid" style="height: 80vh;width:100%" class="ag-theme-alpine"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This was helpful, what I was looking for:     console.log("RowID:", event.data.YOUR_ROW_ID_COL_NAME, "Column:", event.column.colId, "Data:", event.data[event.column.colId])